# popBackStackImmediate() returns to blank screen

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm working on creating a list of workouts, which is displayed using RecycleViewer and populated using RecycleViewer Adapter and ViewHolder. The RecycleViewer is contained within a fragment.

The goal is to display a new fragment showing list of exercises for a selected (clicked) workout.

I managed to replace the fragment with new fragment for displaying list of exercises, however when I press the back button a blank screen is displayed. I'm not sure what is causing this behaviour. Ideally, when pressed back button, WorkoutsListFragment would be displayed again.

Can you help me understand and solve this issue please?

In my WorkoutsActivity I have this:

```
public class WorkoutsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WorkoutsListFragment.onWorkoutSelectedInterface {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workouts);

    WorkoutsListFragment workoutsListFragment = new WorkoutsListFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.workouts_fragment_container, workoutsListFragment)
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}

@Override
public void onWorkoutSelected(int workoutId) {
    Log.i("****","workout : " + workoutId);
    ViewWorkoutFragment viewWorkoutFragment = new ViewWorkoutFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.workouts_fragment_container, viewWorkoutFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
}
```

To keep is short, in WorkoutsListFragment I have created onWorkoutSelectedInterface and assigned its value in onAttach function, where I get the parent activity.

Then I set up my RecycleViewer in onCreateView function. I pass onWorkoutSelectedInterface to the adapter, from which I pass the same interface to ViewHolder.

My View holder looks like this:

```
 WorkoutListViewHolder(View card, WorkoutsListFragment.onWorkoutSelectedInterface onWorkoutSelectedInterface) {
    super(card);
    this.title = card.findViewById(R.id.workout_card_title);
    this.subTitle = card.findViewById(R.id.workout_card_sub_title);
    this.icon = card.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    this.workoutId = 0;

    card.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        Log.i("view", ""+ this.workoutId);
        onWorkoutSelectedInterface.onWorkoutSelected(9);
    });
}
```

Full code can be found on GitHub: 
https://github.com/michalorestes/getFitApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/jds/fitnessjunkiess/getfitapp/Activities/WorkoutsActivity

Thanks in advance for looking in to this :)

**UPDATE:**

I think I'm getting closer to understanding this issue. 
As weird as it may sound, this.dataSet.clear() removes all data in the property (as expected) and in the argument (unexpected!). Therefore, when running this.dataSet = dataSet; views are not shown because there is no data to display. Looks like both variables are pointing to the same memory location :/

```
 public void swapData(List<Workout> dataSet){
    if (this.dataSet != null) {
        this.dataSet.clear();
        this.dataSet.addAll(dataSet);
    }
    else {
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the blank screen is the previous fragment which has not initialized it's views?

Comment: You're correct @MarcEstrada . I added Log to onResume in every fragment and I can see it is going back to the WorkoutListFragment but uninitialised views. Does this mean the only option to get back the views would be by re-initialising them in onResume function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing my swap function to:

```
    public void swapData(List<Workout> data){
    this.dataSet = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Yes, when you pass a list as a parameter, you are passing its reference. Then the adapter and your list variable are pointing at the same piece of memory. If you modifies one variable, the other is also changed. So when you do clear data, you are cleaning your local list variable too. That's why your screen was blank.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and help with finding out what went wrong :) Do you know what sort of materials I could read to learn more about this subject?

Comment: About adapters or about passing variables as parameters by reference?